# Why I'm experiencing boot up issues a few days after swapping my CPU?

Tags: cpu, bios, power-supply, desktop-computer, amd-ryzen

I’m experiencing issues on my PC few days after I swapped the CPU, AIO and SSD. I was playing a game when my PC abruptly turns off and restarts, and whenever it gets to desktop or even in the login screen, it turns off (but leaves the fans spinning and RGB on) and restarts again. I can get to UEFI settings normally and won’t encounter any issues, and it is recognizing all my hardware correctly.

After trying swapping the SSD, the CPU cooler, the GPU, and the RAM, I found out that when swapping back to my previous CPU, it runs normally, I even run stress test for both CPU and GPU to make sure it works as expected.

What could be the issue for my PC?

My Hardware specs are:

```
Ryzen 3 2200G(Old)
Ryzen 7 5700X (New)
RTX 4060 Asus Dual
1x8GB DDR4 ram (currently waiting for my 16GB kit RAM to arrive)
Asrock B450M Steel Legend
Corsair CV650 PSU
Deepcool LS520 SE
Crucial 500GB
```

Note: I updated UEFI to the latest version - 4.6 - before swapping CPU.

Comment: I would say that this is signs of ESD-related damage... Do you know what it is, did you take precautions when replacing the CPU?